# maven jetty plug in mvn:jetty ServletContext.getRealPath("") and ServletRequest.getRealPath("") to point to target _instead_ of source folders?

Tags: maven-2, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

SUMMARY: The goal is to find the path to the WEB-INF folder in the *target* folder for maven-jetty-plugin that is compatible with other servers as well. The ServletContext.getRealPath("") works beautifully for, e.g., Tomcat, or mvn jetty:run-war. Thank you

Misha

---

Dear All:

This is related to
http://tickets.openmrs.org/browse/TRUNK-1760

It can be easily tested with the following commands:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-light-struts-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=2.1.0-M1 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject
cd myproject
patch -p0 < diff
cd myproject
mvn clean install -DskipTests && mvn jetty:run
```

Please find the diff file here:
http://old.nabble.com/file/p29815681/diff

Now, navigate to
http://localhost:8080/
in a browser and this will point to
!!! /home/misha/workspace/myproject/src/main/resources

Should this not, instead, point to?

./target/classes

or

./target/myproject-2.1.0-M1/WEB-INF/classes

Is it possible to modify this behavior?

Thank you so much

Yours

Misha Koshelev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems one work around, per Jan Bartel's very helpful post on the user at jetty dot codehaus dot org mailing list, is to use

mvn jetty:run-exploded

I believe one of the disadvantages of this method is the extra time that it will take to first assemble a WAR and then to run it.

Thank you
Misha

p.s. Reference to Jan Bartel's post:
http://markmail.org/message/445huiwr6vljblxn